# Can not call class variables

Tags: c#

i have a class called ChartEx

```
 public class ChartEx
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
}
```

i am trying to call it from my code behind

```
List<int> lstXaxis = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11, 12 };
List<ChartEx> lstseries = new List<ChartEx>();
```

It is able to recognize `List<int> lstXaxis = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11, 12 };` but shows error on `List<ChartEx> lstseries = new List<ChartEx>();`

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you attempting to initialize a non-static variable in a static method?

Comment: is this asp.net, winforms? Please show the full context of your code.

Comment: I paste your code. There is no problem!

Comment: @Icarus, whether it's ASP.NET or Windows Forms should be really irrelevant. Syntax-wise that code is okay, so the error is something else.

Comment: Are you using WinForms?

Comment: @icarus: yes its a web app

Comment: Where you have your class? same file or another?

Comment: @KageRai We need the error text to help.

Comment: @user1848739: i created that on app_code(another file)

Comment: error's here <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="deafult.aspx.cs" Inherits="deebujacob.deafult" %> parse error

Comment: Try using namespace.ChartEx where namespace is your appcode file namespace where you have your class.

Comment: thank you @user1848739 that was so useful xoxo :)

Comment: @user1848739: yes it did :)

Comment: @KageRai you can upvote or accept answer if it resolved your problem.. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using namespace.ChartEx where namespace is your appcode file namespace where you have your class.